# javascript 'this' value inconsistencies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scope, this

I'm trying to understand why this works:

```
let user = {
  name: 'John',
  age: 30,
  sayHi() {
    console.log(this.name); // works. This defined.
  }
}
```

But the 'this' value here is undefined:

```
  const testRoutes = [
    {
      path: '/home',
      exact: true,
      isPrivate: true,
      header: (
        <span>
          <i className='fas fa-home' />
          &nbsp; Home
        </span>
      ),
      main() {
        console.log(this); // undefined
      },
    },
  ];
```

### Update

Okay, so I figured out the problem was that I was destructuring the object arguments.

## Destructuring the object and calling main results in an undefined `this`:

```
  testRoutes.map(({ path, exact, isPrivate, main }) => {
    main(); // undefined
  });
```

## But this works as expected:

```
  testRoutes.map(route => {
    route.main(); // this is defined
  });
```

I still find this very bizarre and would like to understand why this is happening.

Comment: `this` changes depending on how the function is called. How is it called?

Comment: FYI: I've found *this* to be frustrating in this way too, so I stopped using it whenever possible.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I think you're right. The component is being called with with Route from react-router-dom. When I just map through and call main() it works.